# Flask doesn't redirect on POST method

Tags: python, http, flask

Well, 
I have a button with post method on click

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" onclick="$.post('/test',{'test':'tset'})">Home</button>
```

And flask app, which contains this code

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Nothing happend on button press.I need your help.

Comment: Is the onclick post actually firing? 

Check your network log in developer tools for what is happening to the post request.

Comment: @davidcako yeah, if I add print("POST") in app.py, it works

Comment: Maybe it happens because of POST? I don't know how to fix it

Comment: GET method works nice. It redirects. But i need to post data from login form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're making the request using AJAX/jquery.  A server-side redirect will never work.

The best solution is to just set a client-side callback function:

```
$.post('/test', {'test':'test'}, function(data){
    window.location = data.redirect;
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Using an HTML-based POST would also do what you want, but I'm sure you want to learn how to do it with jquery for a reason.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. Sure this will work. I have another question. When I do redirection to login page again in case of incorrect login/pass, there is a get after post request with redirection. What if I want to show some info about error. I can't do this in callback function, because it will show up in a second, until get request. And then I have clear login page.

Comment: You would generally have a login page use an HTML form-based POST.

If there is ever an imperative for something like this to be AJAX, however, you could always have a callback on it that takes the response data it receives (that's the "data" argument in `function(data)`) and decides whether to yell at you, or to redirect you to the actual *logged in* state.

The response WILL still contain the `data.redirect` field (despite the browser not following it), so if you need to keep the redirect server-side, you can still dynamically use that value, i.e. `window.location = data.redirect`.